My Upload Flow From Power Apps to SharePoint Libraries Doesn't Work
I've created a file upload flow. It simply takes 2 arguments which are FileName and FileContent. Added an attachment control and limited the items to be 1. I don't see any issues with the flow but when I click the my upload button, it does nothing. Literally no errors, no feedbacks, just nothing. At this point I don't know how to solve it and where to search the solution. Any help would be appreciated.
OnSelect Property on Button is following:

UploadFileFlow.Run(
{
file: {
name: First(DataImport_1.Attachments).Name;
contentBytes: First(DataImport_1.Attachments).Value
}
} )



Have you verified that the Power Automate was successfully run? You can remove input parameter "FileName" from [Power Apps (V2)] step as you are not using it in [Create file] step.

Forgot to edit. I solved the problem by changing the directory. I was typing the Folder Path field by hand but it was better with the icon on the right.
